# Passing info in a URL to Sharepoint

Tags: html, sharepoint

I'm new to SharePoint but I was wondering if there was a way to pass variables from an external website to a SharePoint Web Part via GET.

e.g.
http://mysharepointpage.com/sites?name=Jay&age=23 does not populate my name or age input fields in the SharePoint Web Part.

Note: I had to remove the `<form method="GET">` tags because I kept getting an error advising;

```
<FORM> tags are not supported in the HTML specified in either the Content property or the Content Link property. You can 
remove the <FORM> tag, or use the Page Viewer Web Part, which supports the HTML <FORM> tag. The Content property can 
be modified in the Rich Text Editor or Source Editor. More about the Page Viewer Web Part
```

When I click on the link it tells me;

```
Cannot display help.
Technical details: HC not found.
```

I'm guessing this is why I can't retrieve the data via URL.

A little more information as to how would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query string looks correct:
[Connect a Query String (URL) Filter Web Part to another Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Connect-a-Query-String-URL-Filter-Web-Part-to-another-Web-Part-8fd0107f-4889-451b-a7f7-d1996e12a8d1?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA)

You will then need to implement javascript on the page to loop through all the keys and populate the form as required.

You should be able to use this link to help you with your javascript or please post what you are currently using: [Getting query string values in JavaScript](http://blog.vossers.com/2012/08/30/getting-query-string-values-in-javascript/)